# How to avoid hard coding values in cucumber features?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

When writing my scenerios, is it possible to not have to hard code text in the steps?

Like say I am insert a username in a textbox field, and a password in the password field.

If I need to do this in many places, it would be a pain to fix.

Example:

```
Given I am the registered member "myusername"
And I am on the login page
When I fill in "email" with "email@example.com"
And I fill in "password" with "123"
And I press "Login"
Then I should see "Account Activity"
```

I don't want my username, email, and password hard-coded.

Comment: Please show us real examples.

Comment: @RyanBigg updated with an example.

Comment: Isn't this a little counter to cucumbers purpose of writing stories that are testable and very readable even to the non techie. If we start mixing in variables the readability goes a bit out of the window. Might as well just use Rspec with capybara and selenium then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, you're still using the older version of the `cucumber-rails` gem  which comes with the training wheels installed by default. Read this post by Aslak Hellesøy ["The training wheels came off"](http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off).

The gist of the post is that using `web_steps.rb`, although it having been the "standard" for *years* is now terribly wrong and that we should feel bad for doing that.

The purpose of Cucumber is to use it to make readable / understandable features for all people.

Writing a scenario like this is long and boring:

```
And I am on the login page
When I fill in "email" with "email@example.com"
And I fill in "password" with "123"
And I press "Login"
Then I should see "Account Activity"
```

What you want to actually be testing is that you should be able to login and after that see something to do with being logged in. Whatever that something is *shouldn't be written in the scenario*.

So ideally, your `Scenario` (in a more *exciting* fashion) would look like this:

```
When I login successfully
Then I should see that I am logged in
```

Then the task of doing the legwork goes to some new step definitions. Those two steps aren't defined automatically for you, like `web_steps.rb` does, but rather need to have them written in a file within `feature/step_definitions`. What you call the file is up to you, but it'll contain content similar to this:

```
When /I login successfully/ do
  visit root_path
  click_link "Login"
  fill_in "Email", :with => "you@example.com"
  fill_in "Password", :with => "password"
end

Then /^I should see I am logged in$/ do
  page.should have_content("Account Activity")
end
```

No more excessive `web_steps.rb` file and cleaner step definitions. Exactly what Cucumber should be.

Answer (score 0):

Create a step to encapsulate the logging in behavior as described [here](http://blog.mattwynne.net/2008/11/14/dry-up-your-cucumber-steps/)

If this works for you, I would then suggest tweaking the Given /I am logged in/ step to capybara calls to get a slight boost to performance.  Also, in the future it is recommended that you avoid using web_steps for reasons described [here](http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off).

Answer (score 0):

Ryan's example is a change from imperative steps to declarative. This is generally a better idea. It means that the implementation has been moved into step definitions which makes the feature more readable and focuses on the behavior instead of the details.

But if you need to be specific with your steps (imperative), you could try something like

```
Given I am a registered member
And I am on the login page
When I fill in the login form
And I submit the login form
Then I should see I am logged in
```

You could also combine those steps to make it even simpler. But still, Ryan's idea is probably better in most cases.

Edit: Ryan has written a book. It's quite good. Hi Ryan!

Answer (score 0):

You can create csv file in framework under data folder,add your private values to csv file, then call it in your feature file